# Android disable exit application from an activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I got 3 activities in an application.

1. MainActivity
2. ListActivity
3. ChildAvtivity

I am redirecting from an activity to another using the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

And when user press the "back" button, the application must EXIT.

But I want to deny this exit from child activity, ie application need to go back to ListActivity when we press back in ChildActivity.

So I coded like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, ChildActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Working fine. But on this scenario

1. We are in `ChildActivity`
2. Press BACK
3. Reach `ListActivity`
4. Press BACK
5. Application exit

On re-launch, it will directly loads the `ListActivity` directly.

But my requirement is each and every time when application launches, need to goto `MainActivity`, ie launching activity.

Any idea for that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which is your main activity? Share manifest..

Comment: @ramesh on back press don't start the activity again ...use finish() to get back to the previous activity

Comment: You probably need `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` to be defined in your MainActivity in AndroidManifest

Comment: There's a difference between re-launching the app and resuming the task.

Answer (score 1):

Use this [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Are you using any other Flags in code or Menifest.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

In your List activity over ride `OnBackPressed()` function and remove/comment

`super.OnBackPressed();`

this will ensure that your app will not exit from your ListActivity.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest MainActivity put

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

Comment: I think it will destroy even application is paused from ChildActivity

Comment: @FatalError That is true, but if he does not want to resume the ChildActivity when the Home button is pressed and the app is relaunched then the above will work.

Comment: How to set in the way that when ever application is paused or Exit from in my case Login activity it must restart and destroy everything but not from other activity if it is paused from other activity it must resume it rather than restarting Login or clearing all activity

Comment: In your case i think if there is any background work it will through exception

Comment: @FatalError there is no Login in activity in this post. For this post, there question is whether or not the PO wants to resume the ChildActivity if it is on the stack.

Comment: @FatalError You should post a question with some activities flow. I need to know if Login is the launcher activity.

Comment: I think you should post your own question. If Login is the launcher then if it is paused or exit then at that time it is the only activity on the stack, so I do not understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for u

On the XML file do this

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:onClick="goBack"
            android:src="@drawable/back_btn" />
```

And in the Activity Class

```
public void goBack(View v) {
            finish();
     }
```

Or u Can Try Dis also

```
Intent inte = new Intent(YourMainActivity, NewActivity);
inte.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(inte);
finish();
```